# Cirrussearch results in Mediawiki

Tags: elasticsearch, mediawiki

when I search in my private wiki for a word that it is located in different sections on the same page it only displays the first section where the word is located omitting the rest of the appearances

I am using cirrussearch 0.2 as my search engine for mediawiki 1.23.4

Any help will be appreciated

PV

Comment: That's the correct behavior, what do you expect?

Comment: I was expecting to show all the findings for the word by section. At the moment it is showing it to me in the following format:   " Page Name (section "word searched" )"

Comment: That's correct, i don't know, that this would be configurable.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try the fancy highlighter Wikimedia uses, found at https://git.wikimedia.org/project/search , and customise it for your snippet needs.